# WebView : WebViewClient.onPageStarted method is not called

Tags: android, android-widget

Please help me this question.
I am working with webview. And I faced two problem :

1. When the webview loading new page. The onPageStarted method is not called but the onPageFinished method is called.
2. The method :mWebView.canGoBack() always return false.

If you know why or have any suggest please help me.
Note : I am working with : Jquery Mobile in server side(Web side).

Those are my Webview client and Webview init source code.

```
    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient{

    private static final String TAG = "MyWebViewClient";


    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        Log.v(TAG, "onPageFinished url: " + url);

    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url){
        Log.v(TAG, "onLoadResource url: " + url);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        Log.v(TAG, "onPageStarted url: " + url);

    }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
            String description, String failingUrl) {
        super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
        Log.v(TAG, "onReceivedError url: " + failingUrl);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        Log.v(TAG, "shouldOverrideUrlLoading : " + url);

        return false;
    }

}
```

This is my webview init :

```
            mWebView =  new WebView(getActivity());
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        String link = getArguments().getString(PARAMETER_LINK);
        boolean deleteWVData = getArguments().getBoolean(PARAMETER_DELETE_DATA);
        if(deleteWVData)
            mWebView.clearCache(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe `onPageStarted` is only called when a **new** page is loaded. 
E.g.g you are on index.html and navigate to contact.html

Most mobile frameworks (like, jquery mobile, ionic, angualar) will stay on the index.html page and only modify the content. Hence, onPageStarted is not called, but onPageFinished is

Answer (score 0):

```
index.html#xxxxxxx
index.html#aaaaaa
```

are considered the same by the `WebView`,in this case,`onPageStarted` wont'be called

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Comment: webview only calls onPageStarted when loading a new page

Answer (score 0):

Update the webview and check.

I faced this issue when the current version of webview is 60.0.3112.107 while the version in the phone was 57.x.xxxx.xxx